# Search 2 dimensional array for tableView objC

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have a list of results in an array that contains a Name and URL for each main object.

The name is what will be searched and the URL is the image that displays with each row in the TableView.

How can i search and filter the results on only the first sub object?

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope: (NSString*)scope
{
    [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];

    self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.TableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];

}
```

this is not returning anything in the search results. It worked when i had a single array. So how can i search through the TableData on only the first sub object and not the URL.

this is how i populate the array in a previous viewController

```
for(NSDictionary *eachEntry in json)
{
    NSString *entry = [eachEntry objectForKey:@"client"];
    NSString *imageEntry = [eachEntry objectForKey:@"imgLogo"];
    [_tableData addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:entry, imageEntry, nil]];
}
```

EDIT

I still want the search results to contain both objects as it will make displaying the correct image easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the entry and image in a dictionary, you can search using the key.

```
for(NSDictionary *eachEntry in json)
{
    NSString *entry = [eachEntry objectForKey:@"client"];
    NSString *imageEntry = [eachEntry objectForKey:@"imgLogo"];
    [_tableData addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:entry, @"entry", imageEntry, @"imageEntry", nil]];
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope: (NSString*)scope
{
    [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entry contains[c] %@", searchText];

    self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.TableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer dude, this works a treat, Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Tried the same code as you provide. It give filtered result correctly. Make sure your data is filled.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     [searchResult removeAllObjects];

     tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     NSString *entry = @"client";
     NSString *imageEntry = @"imageEntry";
     [tableData addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:entry, imageEntry, nil]];


     NSString *searchText = @"client";
     NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];

     searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
     NSLog(@"%@", searchResult);
}
```

[image]

Comment: oh ok i will have a look now, i take it this will also search the url, is there anyway to stop it, otherwise i will get results that don't make any sense.

Comment: could you try adding more objects and see if it works, just repeat this line [tableData addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:entry, imageEntry, nil]]; a few times. My TableData definitely has data init

Comment: Yes added 5-6 objects to tableData. And get the correct result.

Comment: How to you declare searchResult? i cant see what is different with  mine

Comment: NSMutableArray *tableData;
NSMutableArray *searchResult;

Comment: ok so if i search for the exact obj name it returns results, but with this code if i search for client i should only have to type 'c' and it should find it. It worked like this before i changed the array to a multi array. Any ideas?